# HowTo pass List<T> object to Javascript in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna do something like that:

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
{
    calendarGrid.create(@Model.Events)
}
```

Model.Events is a List.

I tried to use:

- System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(@Model.Events)
- JSON.parse(@Model.Events)
- JSON.strigngify(@Model.Events)

nothing helps.

Comment: What is the `T`? Is it serializable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write code that will serialize your server-side list into code that gets sent to the client. Trye something like this:

```
calendarGrid.Create(@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Model.Events)))
```

The entire contents of `@Html.Raw(...)` will be emitted to the output.

Comment: Actually that should be `calendarGrid.Create(@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Model.Events)))` as the `@` method HTML encodes and the output of the `JavaScriptSerializer` shouldn't be encoded in this case as it already does this.

Comment: it works. What's the right way to add DateTime conversion if my <T> has DateTime properties?

Answer (score 2):

I've had great success by setting a javascript variable to it, using:

```
<script>
     var eventList = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Events)));

     $(document).ready(function () {
        calendarGrid.create(eventList);
     });

</script>
```

From there, you can freely use the eventList variable as a JSON object.

The Trick is the use of Html.Raw to prevent any further encoding from happening